# Microsoft Azure Navigation - Non Technical

Tags: azure, cost-management

Anyone has setup subscription in Microsoft Azure before? I need to choose a No technical support subscription but I am not able to find screen like below:
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about product/service support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options that you see in this screen are available when you perform an upgrade from an [Azure free account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/) or [Azure for Students Starter account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0144p/) to [pay-as-you-go](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0003p/) in the Azure portal.

If you've signed up for an Azure for Students Starter account and are eligible for an Azure free account, you can upgrade to a free account. You'll get $200 of Azure credits and 12 months of free services on upgrade.

Check [Upgrade your Azure free account or Azure for Students Starter account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/upgrade-azure-subscription) to know the detailed steps.